# Incremental export ( daily changes) from Amazon RDS Oracle Table to Amazon S3

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS and exploring solutions for my use case as defined below

**Objective:** To export the incremental changes from Oracle RDS (as on that day i.e every day nightly batch) to Amazon S3 in a scheduled fashion ( automatic)

As of my understanding, I could think of the below options for the same

1. AWS Data pipeline
2. Using Custom Pipeline i.e using Cloudwatch ->Lambda -> Invoking EC2-> invoking SP to extract the data -> using the Python to invoke and upload the results to S3

Do we have any other options to address this case?

Also could you please guide me on the best optimistic ( including Cost) approach

Thanks & Regards,
Damo